# How to add a lower level submenu at a specific position in a context menu?

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu, box, slidedown

Menu example url: 
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

Snapshot:

[image: snapshot :]

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as example: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/fqx4cm2c/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/fqx4cm2c/)

You can add lower level submenu by adding anchor element in div with class "sdt_box"

```
<ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
            <span class="sdt_active"></span>
            <span class="sdt_wrap">
                <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <div class="sdt_box">
            <a href="#">Websites</a>
            <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
            <a href="#">Photography</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```